# scalaz-stream: how to handle the "header" (first chunks) in a different way to the rest?

Tags: scala, scalaz-stream

> Context: I'm trying to write a `Process1[ByteVector, spray.http.HttpResponsePart]` with output `ChunkedResponseStart(bytes), MessageChunk(bytes), MessageChunk(bytes), ..., ChunkedResponseEnd`. I haven't yet fully wrapped my head around scalaz-stream and its vocabulary.

How to write a Process that can handle first `n` chunks differently?

I've come up with this (strings as an example):

```scala
val headerChunk = process1.chunk[String](5).map(_.reduce(_ + _))

val headerChunkAndRest: Process1[String, String] =
  headerChunk.take(1) ++ process1.id

io.linesR(Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("testdata/fahrenheit.txt")))
  .pipe(headerChunkAndRest)
  .to(io.stdOutLines)
  .run.run
```

What is an idiomatic and, possibly, a generally composable way to write `headerChunkAndRest`?

Comment: Do you need access to the contents of the header while processing the rest of the lines?

Comment: Scodec-streams (Scalaz streams to decode and encode binary content) has a good example that might solve your problem: d1 ++ d2: Run d1 and emit all its decoded values, then run d2 on the remaining input and emit its values. Example: decode.once(codecs.int32) ++ decode.advance(12) decodes a single signed Int, then advances the cursor by 12 bits. (https://github.com/scodec/scodec-stream#decoding)

Comment: @TravisBrown no, its contents are not needed for processing the rest. In my case the first chunk should contain the same kind of data as the rest the chunks (parts of a file), it's just a smaller chunk, to be sent to the client earlier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## General Considerations

There are several ways to do this, strongly depending on the details of your needs. You can use the following helper methods that are part of scalaz-streams:

1. `foldWithIndex` This gives you the current index of the chunk as a number. You can discriminate based on that index
2. `zipWithState` You can add a state from one invocation of your method to the next and use this state to track if you are still parsing headers or a if you have reached the body. In the next step you can then use this state to handle header and body different
3. `repartition` Use this to group all header and all body elements together. You can then process them in the next step.
4. `zipWithNext` This function always presents you the previous element grouped with the current element. You can use this to detect, when you are switching from header to body and react accordingly.

Possibly you should re-think, what you really need. For exactly your question, it would be `zipwithIndex` and then `map`. But if you re-think your problem, you will probably end with `repartition` or `zipWithState`.

## Example code

Let's make a simple example: A HTTP client, that separates the HTTP header elements from the body (HTTP, not HTML). In the header a things like cookies, in  the body is the real "content", like an image or the HTTP sources.

A simple HTTP client could look like this:

```
import scalaz.stream._
import scalaz.concurrent.Task
import java.net.InetSocketAddress
import java.nio.channels.AsynchronousChannelGroup

implicit val AG = nio.DefaultAsynchronousChannelGroup

def httpGetRequest(hostname : String, path : String = "/"): Process[Nothing, String] =
  Process(
    s"GET $path HTTP/1.1",
    s"Host: $hostname",
    "Accept: */*",
    "User-Agent: scalaz-stream"
  ).intersperse("\n").append(Process("\n\n"))

def simpleHttpClient(hostname : String, port : Int = 80, path : String = "/")(implicit AG: AsynchronousChannelGroup) : Process[Task, String] =
  nio.connect(new InetSocketAddress(hostname, port)).flatMap(_.run(httpGetRequest(hostname, path).pipe(text.utf8Encode))).pipe(text.utf8Decode).pipe(text.lines())
```

Now we can use this code to separate header lines from the rest. In HTTP, the header is structured in lines. It is separated from the body by an empty line. So first, let's count the number of lines in the header:

```
val demoHostName="scala-lang.org" // Hope they won't mind...
simpleHttpClient(demoHostName).zipWithIndex.takeWhile(! _._1.isEmpty).runLast.run
// res3: Option[(String, Int)] = Some((Content-Type: text/html,8))
```

When I ran this, there were 8 lines in the header. Let's first define an enumeration, so classify the parts of the response:

```
object HttpResponsePart {
  sealed trait EnumVal
  case object HeaderLine extends EnumVal
  case object HeaderBodySeparator extends EnumVal
  case object Body extends EnumVal
  val httpResponseParts = Seq(HeaderLine, HeaderBodySeparator, Body)
}
```

And then let's use `zipWithIndex` plus `map` to classify the parts of the response:

```
simpleHttpClient(demoHostName).zipWithIndex.map{
  case (line, idx) if idx < 9 => (line, HeaderLine)
  case (line, idx) if idx == 10 => (line, HeaderBodySeparator)
  case (line, _) => (line, Body)
}.take(15).runLog.run
```

For me, this works fine. But of course, the amount of header lines can change at any time without notice. It is much more robust to use a very simple parser that considers the structure of the response. for this I use `zipWithState`:

```
simpleHttpClient(demoHostName).zipWithState(HeaderLine : EnumVal){
  case (line, HeaderLine) if line.isEmpty => HeaderBodySeparator
  case (_, HeaderLine) => HeaderLine
  case (_, HeaderBodySeparator) => Body
  case (line, Body) => Body
}.take(15).runLog.run
```

You can see, that both approaches use a similar structure and both approaches should lead to the same result. The fine thing is, both approaches are easily reusable. You can just swap out the source, e.g. with a file, and don't have to change anything. Same with the processing after the classification. The `.take(15).runLog.run` is exactly the same in both approaches.